# Expand logo with jquery, it's possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a doubt regarding jquery (I believe that using the same will solve what I need) I had an idea for the logo at the top of the page, but have not found an effect that can solve this I thought, is the following in the first image:

[image]

the logo is static, when you hover over the logo showing his text spans, example:

[image]

is this possible?

Comment: to answer your question directly it is possible

Comment: The question is slightly confusing: should the image change on hover, or should only the text change?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough demo for you, using just HTML / CSS:

HTML

```
<h1>Logo
    <span>More Stuff</span>
    <div>Square</div>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 0.5s ease 0s;
}

h1:hover span {
    height: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Did it work before you edited it? What didn't work and what browser are you using so I can try it.